# Capslock as Escape Key hold vs press behavior

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, capslock

I would like to know if it's possible to map CapsLock as Escape key when tapping but behave as a Super key if hold.

This is a behavior I manage to do in MacOS with Karabiner but I haven't been able to replicate here.

The whole behavior I'm looking for is the following:

- Swap CapsLock and Escape key.
- Tap CapsLock for Escape.
- Hold CapsLock for Super.

Comment: Search for `xcape`; You will have to use Xorg, not Wayland (which is usually a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

**1** The easy part will be to **swap CapsLock and Escape**. This can be done with the xkb options:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:super
```

This can be enabled automatically and systemwide in the configuration file `/etc/default/keyboard` by editing `XKBOPTIONS=""`. To configure a user account, include the command in `~/.profile`. Gnome Shell can override keyboard options in the gsettings key "org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options" and can be set using Tweaks.

**2a.** When on **Xorg, implementing Esc** when hitting and releasing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is also easy.

```
xcape -e "Hyper_L=Escape"
```

`Hyper_L` is the code assigned to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> after applying the option. You can see that in the output of `xev`. Names of keys can be seen in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`.

Create an autostart entry or include the command in `~/.profile` to have it automatically started.

**2b.** It is a lot more difficult but not impossible to implement this in **Wayland**. Alternatives for Wayland include ([source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24926031)):

https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys

https://gitlab.com/at-home-modifier/at-home-modifier-evdev

https://github.com/myfreeweb/evscript

https://github.com/wbolster/evcape

and all have their specific setup.